# Sum of squares of any three consecutive even integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There is this question and my solution. But I am not sure whether there is anything to add to my solution.

What conclusions can you draw about the sum of the squares of any three consecutive even integers? Write down clearly how you come to these conclusions. You get more marks for generating interesting and novel answers. You should give as many solutions as possible.

Below is as far as I can get.

**Edited**
$$(2n)^2+(2n+2)^2+(2n+4)^2=4(3n^2+6n+5)$$

What else can I say about this? Has a factor of 4? **But I don't find $4(3n^2+6n+5)$ particularly interesting..** Is there any other interesting thing about this conclusion? Or is there any better conclusion?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check your algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Why not denote the three consecutive *even* integers as $\;2n-2\,,\,2n\,,\,2n+2\;$ ? Wouldn't it be easier? :

$$(2n-2)^2+ (2n)^2+(2n+2)^2=12n^2+8=4(3n^2+2)$$

Comment: Thanks but is it supposed to be sum instead of product?

Comment: Sorry, edited @user71346

Answer (score 0):

$$(2n)^2+(2n+2)^2+(2n+4)^2=12n^2+24n+20=4(3n^2+6n+5)$$
is, of course, divisible by $4$, and for any $n$, 
$$12n^2+24n+20\equiv 2\pmod{3},$$
$$12n^2+24n+20\equiv 2\pmod{6},$$
$$12n^2+24n+20\equiv 8\pmod{12}.$$